# Image linked to CSS not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have a image in my CSS that isn't showing up. I'm not good with CSS, so I don't know what I might done wrong. I remade the file structure, before that was working fine. I don't know what I did wrong on changing the path in my CSS file. If a click to follow the link in vscode it opens the image.

The CSS:

```css
.home_banner_area {
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(../img/home-banner.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover; }
```

The HTML where the image should render:

```html
<section class="home_banner_area">
        <div class="banner_inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="home_left_img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="resources/img/home-left.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="banner_content">
                            <h2>
                                For All Occasion <br>
                                HairStyle is a Must <br>
                                Try Fashion
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp or incididunt ut labore et dolore
                                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

My file structure:

[image: File Structure]

**Edit:**

For some reason it has both home_banner_area and banner_area, I edited with the right one. My bad.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Make sure your background is on a _visible_ element with _non-zero height and width_.

Comment: You don't have a class called `.banner_area`. Only `.home_banner_area`

Comment: What file is the one with the HTML? index.php?

Comment: @rblarsen I has the two classes. Idk why.

Comment: @SebastianSimon the console is going to a folder that don't even exists. It goes to img/banner/home-banner.jpg

Comment: _“I don't know what I did wrong on changing the path in my CSS file.”_ - if you actually mean you changed this in the `style.css` file … well then _that_ is most likely what you did wrong. I see an `scss` folder there, so that likely means your project is using SASS – so any style changes should be made in the SASS files, that then get compiled _into_ the `style.css` again (either automatically, or by calling some command line tool, depends on what exactly your setup is.)

Comment: @misorude makes sense, since it's trying to get from the old folder. I will try and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be refering to the div element on the CSS by its class name? You have ".banner_area" and there is not element on your HTML with that class name. Rename it on your CSS.

Comment: I has to classes, I only saw it now. Idk why, but I edited

Comment: Did it work? Also make sure you have no troubles linking the HTML to the CSS.

Comment: I didn't work. The CSS link is fine, everything else is working

Comment: Have you tried with the "background-image" property and then using the "background-repeat:no-repeat", and then "background-position:center"?

Answer (score 0):

The path passed in the css property must be relative to the page context and not to the file system. To find out the path of the image, try to access the image url using the browser and enter the context path in the `url()` property.

For example:

if the site opens in `localhost:8080/` and the folder with images is mapped on your http server, possibly the path will be `localhost:8080/img/home-banner.png`, then, the path to be inserted in the `background-image` will be `/img/home-banner.png`.

Comment: Well, the image opens. But like I said in the question comment, for some reason it's trying to render from resources/img/banner/home-banner.jpg, the banner folder existed in the old structure

Comment: “Page context” is a rather imprecise way of phrasing it. Relative URLs inside an external stylesheet are considered relative to the URL of the stylesheet, not “the page” …

Comment: You're right @misorude. What do you suggest to imrpove this awnser? Thanks

Comment: Just make it say that relative URLs inside stylesheets are considered relative to the stylesheet location, not that of the embedding document, then that part should be adequately covered. (This becomes important for example if you wanted to provide some styling component for other websites to embed, and you want to load background images from your server as well - otherwise you’d have to use full absolute URLs all the time for that to work.)